# Force mysql service to stop

Tags: mysql

I know that this is a simple question:

#### How to stop mysql server?

but under root(in a linux server) `service mysql stop`displays `Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld` and it waits for an infinite time and the status shows that the service is alway running. So how to FORCE mysql server to stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried killing the deamon directly?

```
killall mysqld
```

Have to warn you, this could lead to corrupted unrecoverable databases...

Comment: There are risks, like unrecoverable database, since you don't know if the deamon is writing to the databases or not.

Comment: Is there a safe way to do that?

Comment: yes I stops but once I try service mysql stop it stays hanged

Comment: I restarted the server but during stoping the services mysql service stopping process is not working and know it stop the server fron being restarted.is was a bad idea to start the server as a solution :(

Comment: How much CPU is the sql server using? Did you initiate a heavy query that's stuk in a loop? That would couse such a thing. If the sql server is doing complex loops and has no inserts or updates in that query you can simply kill it.

Comment: mysqld on TERM signal exits gracefully. So, it's legit way to stop the server. Note killall will stop *all* instances of mysqld

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Or this:

```
sudo initctl stop mysql
```

Answer (score -5):

you can kill that process, runing mysql.

Comment: You should elaborate. That's a low quality answer.